# App opens maximized when it should not

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winforms application with a fixed-size starting dialog. After making some changes entirely unrelated to this form, the form now opens maximized, filling the entire screen with the actual content still at the regular size in upper left corner. Dragging the title bar down a bit with the mouse causes it to restore to its appropriate size.

The form has

```
MaximizeBox = False
StartPosition = CenterScreen
FormBorderStyle = Fixed3D
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be causing it to open maximized, and how to stop it?

Edit:

```
WindowState = Normal
```

is also set.

Edit 2:

I found the problem. My update routine was shutting down the original process so it could be updated (inappropriately, but that is a different bug), then restarting it with code I had borrowed from elsewhere, and part of that restart code was:

```
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
```

Thank you for the assistance. Though no direct answer was given (nor expected with the spotty information), it did point me in the right direction.

Comment: What are the "unrelated" changes. Those 3 lines of code (if executed, in a constructor or load event) seem okay. You should also make sure the WindowState of the form is not WindowState.Maximised.

Comment: `MaximizeBox ` indicating that Maximize button is appeared. Check `WindowState ` property, it should be `Normal`, not `Maximized`

Comment: Thank you. WindowState is normal, as I've just added. The unrelated changes were to an installer/updater.

Comment: roll back your changes, make them one at a time and test, and isolate which is causing your issue.

Comment: Have any code in the Form.Shown, Form.Load events that could be messing with you? Or - look at the code that's opening the form...that could be messing with you, too. All those properties can be set at runtime.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets in your question. is there a "Load" event handler hooked in? or is your constructor interesting? We need something to go on than pure speculation of "there is a problem help"

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  I don't see any.  Add an event handler for the Resize event, set a breakpoint on it and look at the Call Stack window to see why it happened.  Do note that it will break at least twice from normal initialization.

Comment: I found the problem. It was in the update routine where the process was restarted with an unintended `ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The Window being Maximised is normally set on the forms "WindowState", [Light Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx). You need this to be set to WindowState.Normal. It's possible someone's set it to maximised in the designer? or somewhere else in the code. the 3 lines of code you have shown are not the problem.

Edit:

You need to do some investigation if you cant give us code from your form, Hook into some resize events, and see what's triggered it off. Forms dont just start up maximised unless they're told to and maximizing a window triggers a resize event.

Comment: As I added after you started this reply, WindowState=Normal. But thank you.